# jScrollpane Chrome problem

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jscrollpane

in the "Known issues" at JScrollPane site, there's a:

> In Webkit browsers CSS must be
>   included before Javascript

i did that but sometimes im still getting (only in the first page, the index) some scroll problems, the scroll just disappears and after i refresh the page again its all ok

my browser cache is empty so is not that..
also i tried using:

```
$.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
```

the code im using for my scroll is similar to the ajax example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var api = $('#mydiv').jScrollPane({ showArrows: false, reinitialiseOnImageLoad: true }).data('jsp');
   $('.a_link').live('click', function() { ... ....
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reinitialiseOnImageLoad` is a setting from version 1 of jScrollPane and no longer does anything. If your pane contains images you'll need to use one of these techniques:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image2.html

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html

If that doesn't help please provide a URL or set up an example on http://www.jsfiddle.net/ (or tell me if you can reproduce in the demos on the jScrollPane site).