# Chrome won't scroll

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I'm having a problem in Google Chrome that isn't happening in any other web browser.

Here is the website:
[shop.mischiefshoes.co.nz](http://shop.mischiefshoes.co.nz)

Google Chrome won't scroll, no matter what I do. I've tried looking online for fixes but I can't seem to find anything.

Tips?

Comment: it automatically redirected me on a store-like page, the scroll works on me...

Comment: I opened your website , scrolling shows no problem.

Comment: Really strange - have no idea though :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of
`position:fixed` in `div.footer` if you remove it works fine and you can do some changes in it to make scroll and footer fixed same time.

And I change `#bodywrapper { width:1025px;//from 1024px;}` and it worked for me..

Comment: Where would I find these fixes? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @MichaelR.J.Crosbie I am also finding the issue and soon let you know :)

Comment: Amazing. Sorry, about the slow reply. That's great, thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is happening because of [jQuery incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204864/1577396) with chrome or maybe because of positioning as stated by Arpit Srivastava.

Because when I zoomed the page in or out, it is working fine.
And when I bring the page to normal state, then also it is working.Although after refreshing it is not working again.

You can also use [Zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/) property(CSS3) to overcome this problem.
just give `zoom:101%;` to your `body` tag.
I hope this will work.

Comment: @Michael R. J. Crosbie Try this one and tell me whether it is working or not. [link1](http://www.guidingtech.com/9751/mouse-scroll-not-working-how-to-scroll-chrome-firefox/) or [link2](http://www.pcgeekblog.com/2010/12/scroll-not-working-in-google-chrome.html).

Comment: @Michael R. J. Crosbie Go through these links also [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204864/jscrollpane-chrome-problem) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324563/jscroll-is-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari) [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042651/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox).